# Public database of bibtex entires of LaTeX packages

Tags: bibliographies, ctan

When I want to cite a research paper, I typically look up the respective BibTeX entry in some online catalogue (such as [DBLP](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/) or the [ACM](http://dl.acm.org) and [IEEE](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org) digital libraries for computer science). The quality of the entries is not always great, but at least a good start.

Now I am in the situation that I am writing a research article in which I also need to cite a couple of LaTeX packages. Of course, I could just enter all the respective BibTeX entries manually. However, given how many package documentations cite other packages, I hope that there is some BibTeX database of all CTAN packages available, somewhere?

I found it extremely hard to look for this. As you can imagine, googling for `"latex package" AND bibliography` or variants thereof does yield many, but no useful results.

Comment: I don't know of such a bibliography but you can query ctan and get xml-files: http://www.ctan.org/help/access. It shouldn't be to difficult to create bib-files from them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Edit**: The code is now hosted on [Github](https://github.com/michal-h21/ctanbib).

Thanks to Ulrike, who pointed out existence of the `xml` interface on `CTAN`, I was able to create simple and dumb lua script, using `wget` command and my `luaxml` package.

The idea is that you pass the package name as argument for this script and `biblatex` entry is printed on the standard output. First whole script, `ctanbib.lua`:

```lua
#!/usr/bin/env texlua
kpse.set_program_name("luatex")
-- ctanbib.lua -- export ctan entries to bib format
--

if #arg < 1 or arg[1]=="--help" or arg[1]=="-h" then 
print [[ctanbib - convert ctan package information to bibtex format
Usage:
  texlua ctanbib <package name>

This command will bibtex entry to the terminal output
]]
os.exit(1)
end

local pkgname = arg[1]
local url = "https://www.ctan.org/xml/pkg/" .. pkgname

-- change that for different title scheme
local titleformat = "The %s package"

local bibtexformat = [[
@manual{$package,
title = {$title},
subtitle = {$subtitle},
author = {$author},
url = {$url},
urldate = {$urldate}, 
date = {$date},
version = {$version}
}
]]

local xml = require('luaxml-mod-xml')
local handler = require('luaxml-mod-handler')

local load_xml =  function(url)
    local command = io.popen("wget -qO- ".. url,"r")

    local info = command:read("*all")
    command:close()

    if string.len(info) == 0 then
        return false
    end
    --print(pkginfo)
    treehandler = handler.simpleTreeHandler()
    treehandler.options.noReduce = {authorref=true}
    x = xml.xmlParser(treehandler)
    x:parse(info)
    return treehandler.root
end

local get_authors = function(a)
    local authors = {}
    local retrieved_authors = {}
    -- fix LuaXML "feature" 
    if #a == 0 then a = {a} end
    for _, author in ipairs(a) do
      local current = {}
      current[#current+1] = author._attr.familyname
      current[#current+1] = author._attr.givenname
      table.insert(retrieved_authors, table.concat(current, ", "))
    end
    return table.concat(retrieved_authors," and ")
end

local get_title = function(title)
    local title = title:gsub("^(.)", function(a) return unicode.utf8.upper(a) end)
    return string.format(titleformat, title)
end


local get_url = function(home)
    local home = home or {}
    local attr = home["_attr"] or {}
    local href = attr.href or "http://www.ctan.org/pkg/"..pkgname
    return href
end

local get_version = function(version)
    local version = version or {}
    local attr = version["_attr"] or {}
    return attr["number"], attr["date"]
end

local bibtex_escape = function(a)
    local a = a or ""
    return a:gsub("([%$%{%}])", function(x) return '\\'..x end)
end

local compile = function(template, records)
  return template:gsub("$([a-z]+)", function(a) 
        return bibtex_escape(records[a]) or ""
    end)
end

local entry = load_xml(url)

if not entry then
    print("Cannot find entry for package "..pkgname)
    os.exit(1)
end

-- root element is also saved, so we use this trick 
local record = entry.entry

local e = {}

e.author = get_authors(record.authorref)
e.package = pkgname
e.title = get_title(record.name)
e.subtitle = record.caption
e.url = get_url(record.home)
e.version, e.date = get_version(record.version)
e.urldate = os.date("%Y-%m-%d")

local result = compile(bibtexformat, e)

print(result)
```

to understand this script we need to look at the xml files from ctan:

```xml
<entry id="pgf">
<name>pgf</name>
<caption>Create PostScript and PDF graphics in TeX</caption>
<authorref id="auth:tantau"/>
<authorref id="auth:feuersaenger"/>
<copyright owner="Till Tantau" year="2005-2014"/>
<license type="lppl1.3"/>
<version number="3.0.0" date="2013-12-20"/>
<description>PGF is a macro package for creating graphics.
        It is platform- and format-independent and works together
        with the most important TeX backend drivers, including pdftex and
        dvips. It comes with a user-friendly syntax layer called TikZ. 
        <p/>
        Its usage is similar to
        <ref refid="pstricks">pstricks</ref> and the standard picture
        environment.  PGF works with plain (pdf-)TeX, (pdf-)LaTeX, and
        ConTeXt.  Unlike <ref refid="pstricks">pstricks</ref>, it
        can produce either PostScript or PDF output.</description>
<documentation details="Readme" href="ctan:/graphics/pgf/base/README"/>
<documentation details="PGF Manual" href="ctan:/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf"/>
<documentation details="Minimal introduction to TikZ" href="http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf"/>
<home href="http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/"/>
<ctan path="/graphics/pgf/base" file="true"/>
<install path="/graphics/pgf/base/pgf.tds.zip"/>
<miktex location="pgf"/>
<texlive location="pgf"/>
<keyval key="topic" value="graphics-in-tex"/>
<keyval key="index" value=""/>
</entry>
```

note, that authors are saved in `authorref` elements, which doesn't contain names, but only reference to other file, which hold author info. Also note, that there is no usable title, only package name and caption, which could be used as subtitle.

xml file with author info looks like that:

```xml
<author key="tantau" givenname="Till" familyname="Tantau"/>
```

so for each author, we need to fetch also this file with name.

now we may look at some parts of this script:

```lua
local titleformat = "The %s package"
```

We need format for title because we get only package name.

```lua
local bibtexformat = [[
@manual{$package,
title = {$title},
subtitle = {$subtitle},
author = {$author},
url = {$url},
urldate = {$urldate}, 
date = {$date},
version = {$version}
}
]]
```

These are formats for printing the bibtex entry. `$strings` will be replaced with corresponding parsed fields.

```lua
local load_xml =  function(url)
    local command = io.popen("wget -qO- ".. url,"r")

    local info = command:read("*all")
    command:close()

    if string.len(info) == 0 then
        return false
    end
    --print(pkginfo)
    treehandler = handler.simpleTreeHandler()
    x = xml.xmlParser(treehandler)
    x:parse(info)
    return treehandler.root
end
```

this function fetch the url and returns parsed xml.

```lua
local get_authors = function(a)
    local authors = {}
    local retrieved_authors = {}
    if #a == 0 then 
        table.insert(authors,a) 
    else
        authors = a
    end
    for _, v in ipairs(authors) do
        local id = v["_attr"]["key"]
        local author_url = "http://www.ctan.org/xml/author/".. id
        local authorxml = load_xml(author_url)
        if not authorxml then
            print("Warning: cannot load author info for: " .. id)
        else
            local x = authorxml.author["_attr"]
            table.insert(retrieved_authors, x.familyname.. ", " .. x.givenname)
        end
    end
    return table.concat(retrieved_authors," and ")
end
```

function `load_authors` is the most complex, due to limitation of `luaxml`, because it uses different table structure when there is only one element and when two or more elements exists. after table normalization, xml files are processed for each author and author field is build.

```lua
local get_title = function(title)
    local title = title:gsub("^(.)", function(a) return unicode.utf8.upper(a) end)
    return string.format(titleformat, title)
end
```

the first letter of package name is upper cased (we use unicode library in order to support accented characters). Then `titleformat` is used to build a title.

```lua
local get_url = function(home)
    local home = home or {}
    local attr = home["_attr"] or {}
    local href = attr.href or "http://www.ctan.org/pkg/"..pkgname
    return href
end
```

some packages have `homepage` set, for these which doesn't, we use `ctan` path

```lua
local get_version = function(version)
    local version = version or {}
    local attr = version["_attr"] or {}
    return attr["number"], attr["date"]
end
```

parse version number and release date, not all packages have these!

```lua
local bibtex_escape = function(a)
    local a = a or ""
    return a:gsub("([%$%{%}])", function(x) return '\\'..x end)
end
```

escape special characters. this is very basic version. I assume `biblatex` and `biber` so `utf8` encoding is used. If we want to encode accented characters to `bibtex` codes (like `{\v{c}}`), it would make the script much more complex.

```lua
local compile = function(template, records)
  return template:gsub("$([a-z]+)", function(a) 
        return bibtex_escape(records[a]) or ""
    end)
end
```

function to place values into the template. all fields are in the `records` table

```lua
local e = {}

e.author = get_authors(record.authorref)
e.package = pkgname
e.title = get_title(record.name)
e.subtitle = record.caption
e.url = get_url(record.home)
e.version, e.date = get_version(record.version)
e.urldate = os.date("%Y-%m-%d")

local result = compile(bibtexformat, e)

print(result)
```

there is a table with all fields built and the bibtex entry is printed.

Now we can try the code:

```
texlua ctanbib.lua tex4ht
```

will print:

```
@manual{tex4ht,
title = {The Tex4ht package},
subtitle = {Convert (La)TeX to HTML/XML},
author = {Gurari, Eitan M. and Berry, Karl and Radhakrishnan, C. V.},
url = {http://tug.org/tex4ht},
urldate = {2014-09-12}, 
date = {2008-06-16},
version = {}
}
```

we may use standard methods to pipe output to the file with

```
texlua ctanbib.lua tex4ht > sample.bib
```

and some more files

```
texlua ctanbib.lua luaxml >> sample.bib
texlua ctanbib.lua pgf >> sample.bib
```

we may test the result with some sample file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: If I just create the Lua file and run the command line shown, I get `ctanbib.lua:32: module 'luaxml-mod-xml' not found:`. And, yes, I have `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua`

Comment: A line `kpse.set_program_name("luatex")` seems missing.

Comment: After adding the line mentioned by @egreg it works for me. Great work, I particularly like the attempt to use the `lua` interpreter provided by the the TeX distribution anyway :-)

Comment: One caveat: The output of accented characters is UTF8. This of course is fine with `biblatex` and `bibtex8`, but many scientific venue require `.bbl`-files produced by archaic 7-bit `bibtex`.

Comment: @egreg you are right. I created this answer on my work computer with TL 2012, so I had to manually copy `luaxml` to the working dir and haven't notice that this doesn't work even with newer versions

Comment: @egreg I've edited my answer, it should be OK now

Comment: @Daniel yes, I know, I may add that as an option, I think fontenc tables could be used for conversion from utf8 to LICR (I did it in the other way in the past)

Comment: One more small suggestion: Add a shebang line, that is `#!texlua` as the first line. Then, on UNIX-flavored systems, it is possible to make the script directly executable with a `chmod +x ctanbib.lua` command.

Comment: @you are right, I added shebang, `#!texlua` didn't work for me, I used `/usr/bin/env texlua` instead

Comment: Do many scientific publications include references to TeX packages? (If not is the UTF8 bit really much of a limitation?)

Comment: It seems the API changed (error: `62: attempt to index field 'id' (a nil value)`). Is there a update for that script?

Comment: @LukasCB you are right, there was slight change. I've updated the script and it seems to work now.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the fix. Your code should be implemented on CTAN!

Comment: When I get `69: attempt to concatenate field 'familyname' (a nil value)` it is due to a poorly parsed xml?

Comment: @LukasCB it seems like the familyname of some author is missing. whic package gives you this error?

Comment: its multicol, graphicx (all those by the latex team??)

Comment: @LukasCB ah I see, there is `The LaTeX team` noted as firstname, without familyname.

Comment: @LukasCB I hope I fixed this issue. I also created github repo: https://github.com/michal-h21/ctanbib

Comment: great, i will post further comments in the github repo. thanks!